# Run actions before application terminates Swift Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsapplication

I have several actions to perform before the application quits. They take about 3 or 4 seconds to be done (and may be more, up to 10 secs), and when I try to execute them in `applicationWillTerminate`, only a part of them are done.

I also tried executing them in `applicationShouldTerminate` before `return NSApplicationTerminateReply.TerminateNow`, but still some of them are not performed. How to do all of them and then quit properly?

Comment: Are you sure your tasks only take three to four seconds? According to [the Apple developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=de#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:), using the applicationWillTerminate method, "Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return."

Comment: @BenjaminLowry, actually, now I'm looking for the solution that will allow to run even more code (approximately 8-9 seconds)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the tasks need it to be done when the app is terminated and not just in the background?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry, yes. It's like the clean-up before app quits

Comment: I have read around and it seems to be the consensus that using _applicationDidEnterBackground_ is the safest place to do app clean ups since _applicationWillTerminate_ is only called when the app is terminated while in the foreground. Thus it is safer to always perform the clean ups when your user even just leaves the app. This should also solve your timing issues.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry, and if user has never left app window? The function won't be called, and I'll still need to perform tasks in `applicationShouldTerminate`

Comment: Fair enough. I do not know of any ways to elongate the _applicationWillTerminate_ time, so my biggest suggestion is to cut down your processes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102995/discussion-between-benjamin-lowry-and-nikitin-roman).

Comment: Did you try `TerminateLater` and `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate`?

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful. Handle all of your clean up actions here

```
applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {
    // your tear down logic 
}
```